# Pass parameter to context menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, contextmenu

I am currently studying Material UI 5 and specifically Context Menu subject - https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/#context-menu.

Can someone explain me why the handleClose function always print the last index in the array - 4?

```
import * as React from "react"
import Menu from "@mui/material/Menu"
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem"
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography"

export default function ContextMenu() {
  const [contextMenu, setContextMenu] = React.useState(null)

  const handleContextMenu = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setContextMenu(
      contextMenu === null
        ? {
            mouseX: event.clientX + 2,
            mouseY: event.clientY - 6,
          }
        : null
    )
  }

  const handleClose = (i) => {
    setContextMenu(null)
    console.log(i)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].map((item, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          onContextMenu={handleContextMenu}
          style={{ cursor: "context-menu" }}
        >
          <Typography variant='h6' component='h1' sx={{ padding: 4 }}>
            {item}
          </Typography>
          <Menu
            open={contextMenu !== null}
            onClose={handleClose}
            anchorReference='anchorPosition'
            anchorPosition={
              contextMenu !== null
                ? { top: contextMenu.mouseY, left: contextMenu.mouseX }
                : undefined
            }
          >
            <MenuItem onClick={() => handleClose(index)}>one</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={() => handleClose(index)}>two</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={() => handleClose(index)}>three</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you currently have the on clicks setup is that it accesses the value `index` has at the time you click it, not the value it had when the function was created.

Change

```
onClick={() => handleClose(index)}
```

To

```
onClick={((index) => () => handleClose(index))(index)}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the following code and see how you should manage user's options :

```
import * as React from "react";
import Menu from "@mui/material/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

export default function ContextMenu() {
  const initialState = {
    element: null,
    item: null
  };
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialState);

  const handleListItemClick = (element, item) => {
    setState({
      element,
      item
    });
  };

  const handleMenuItemClick = (option) => {
    setState(initialState);
    switch (option) {
      case "one":
        console.log(state.item, "one");
        break;
      case "two":
        console.log(state.item, "two");
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {React.Children.toArray(
        ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].map((item) => (
          <Typography
            onClick={(e) => handleListItemClick(e.target, item)}
            sx={{ margin: 4 }}
          >
            {item}
          </Typography>
        ))
      )}
      <Menu open={state.element !== null} anchorEl={state.element}>
        <MenuItem onClick={() => handleMenuItemClick("one")}>one</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={() => handleMenuItemClick("two")}>two</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-microservice-w5jh00

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't understand what the role of "React.Children.toArray". I ran the code without this line and still got a good result.

Comment: your welcome, it returns the children opaque data structure as a flat array with keys assigned to each child.